# WebSphere Application Server 7.0.0.33 installation error - "failed to Install Update Installer"

Tags: ibm-was

I ran into errors when trying to install WebSphere Commerce Fix Pack 8 (on WCS FEP 1 and FP 7) and so started WebSphere Commerce installation from scratch. I was able to install RAD but am running into the below error when trying to install WebSphere Application Server 7.0.0.33 (I also tried installing other versions, but ended up having the same error).

Any help and ideas to overcome this problem would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Please note this is: WebSphere Commerce Developer Environment and WebSphere Application Server Test Environment.

**Operating System:** Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit
**Antivirus:** McAfee

**IBM Installation Manager:**
Version: 1.8.0 
Internal version: 1.8.0.20140902_1503
Architecture: 32-bit

**RAD:** 
Succeeded installing the below version:
IBM® Rational® Application Developer™ for WebSphere® Software
Version 7.5.5.5 iFix1 (7.5.5051.RADO7555iFix1-I20120913_1613)

**WebSphere Application Server:**
 Ran into the below error while attempting to install WAS 7.0.0.33
 
 
Error during "install" phase:

Error recorded in the log file: 
actionStep      : -INSTALL
 
version         : 7.0.0.17
 
sourcePath      : C:\IBM\SDP\image\UPDI70
 
installPath     : C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\updi_v70
 
calling performInstall
 
compare = 0
 
Deleting installPath : C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\updi_v70
 
performInstall : Install Update Installer
 
OSCommand : Invoking at : C:\IBM\SDP\image\UPDI70\UpdateInstaller
 
OSCommand : Print out Command
 
C:\IBM\SDP\image\UPDI70\JDK\jre.pak\repository\package.java.jre\java\jre\bin\java.exe
 
-cp
 
setup.jar
 
run
 
-OPT
 
silentInstallLicenseAcceptance=true
 
-OPT
 
allowNonRootSilentInstall=true
 
-OPT
 
disableOSPrereqChecking=true
 
-OPT
 
disableEarlyPrereqChecking=true
 
-OPT
 
skipStartMenu=true
 
-OPT
 
installLocation=C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\updi_v70
 
-silent
 
OSCommand : Done Print out Command
 
Unable to load JNI dll 
 archive:C:\IBM\SDP\image\UPDI70\UpdateInstaller\setup.jar+/6d03fb4a8c94a5cdd9d0f5efa721f948/win32ppk/win32ppk.dll
 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\SHEELA~1.DOS\AppData\Local\Temp\ismp001\win32ppk.dll (Access is denied. )
 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1011)
 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1019)
 
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:781)
 
at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:769)
 
at com.installshield.util.LibraryLoader.loadLibrary(LibraryLoader.java:77)
 
at com.installshield.wizard.platform.win32.Win32Utils.loadDLL(Win32Utils.java:49)
 
at com.installshield.wizard.platform.win32.Win32SystemUtilServiceImpl.initialized(Win32SystemUtilServiceImpl.java:68)
 
at com.installshield.wizard.service.AbstractServiceImplementor.initialize(AbstractServiceImplementor.java:23)
 
at com.installshield.wizard.service.ServiceFactory.createImpl(ServiceFactory.java:129)
 
at com.installshield.wizard.service.ServiceFactory.createService(ServiceFactory.java:55)
 
at com.installshield.wizard.service.ServiceFactory.createService(ServiceFactory.java:24)
 
at com.installshield.wizard.service.LocalWizardServices.loadService(LocalWizardServices.java:107)
 
at com.installshield.wizard.service.LocalWizardServices.getService(LocalWizardServices.java:122)
 
at com.installshield.wizard.service.system.SystemUtilServiceInitialize.execute(SystemUtilServiceInitialize.java:17)
 
at com.installshield.wizard.Wizard.executeStartupBeans(Wizard.java:1451)
 
at com.installshield.wizard.Wizard$RunThread.run(Wizard.java:1534)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for looking into it!

FINALLY figured it out ... turned out McAfee (anti-virus) software was blocking the install.

I was able to successfully install WAS 7.0.0.33 after turning off the McAfee services - specifically the McAfee Host Intrusion Prevention Service.

Answer (score 1):

The error stack seems to indicate a file permission issue:

```
Unable to load JNI dll
archive:C:\IBM\SDP\image\UPDI70\UpdateInstaller\setup.jar+/6d03fb4a8c94a5cdd9d0f5efa721f948/win32ppk/win32ppk.dll
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\SHEELA~1.DOS\AppData\Local\Temp\ismp001\win32ppk.dll ***(Access is denied. )***
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1011)
```

Maybe check privileges for the user installing the product/fix?